intelmpi 2021.1 error on RHEL 8 with error integer divide by zero
After upgrade computation nodes of a HPC cluster from CentOS 7 to a RHEL8.6 Linux distribution (KeyarchOS 5.8), I get report that some software compiled with Intel OneAPI 2021.1 failed to run with mpirun. A typical error is as the follow
[cu345:1485183:0:1485183] Caught signal 8 (Floating point exception: integer divide by zero)
[cu345:1485184:0:1485184] Caught signal 8 (Floating point exception: integer divide by zero)
[cu345:1485185:0:1485185] Caught signal 8 (Floating point exception: integer divide by zero)
[cu345:1485186:0:1485186] Caught signal 8 (Floating point exception: integer divide by zero)
==== backtrace (tid:1485126) ====
 0 0x0000000000012ce0 __funlockfile()  :0
 1 0x0000000000b696ed next_random()  /localdisk/jenkins/workspace/workspace/ch4-build-linux-2019/impi-ch4-build-linux_build/CONF/impi-ch4-build-linux-release/label/impi-ch4-build-linux-intel64/_buildspace/release/../../src/mpid/ch4/shm/posix/eager/include/intel_transport_types.h:1809
 2 0x0000000000b696ed impi_bcast_intra_huge()  /localdisk/jenkins/workspace/workspace/ch4-build-linux-2019/impi-ch4-build-linux_build/CONF/impi-ch4-build-linux-release/label/impi-ch4-build-linux-intel64/_buildspace/release/../../src/mpid/ch4/shm/posix/eager/include/intel_transport_bcast.h:667
 3 0x0000000000b6630d impi_bcast_intra_heap()  /localdisk/jenkins/workspace/workspace/ch4-build-linux-2019/impi-ch4-build-linux_build/CONF/impi-ch4-build-linux-release/label/impi-ch4-build-linux-intel64/_buildspace/release/../../src/mpid/ch4/shm/posix/eager/include/intel_transport_bcast.h:798
 4 0x000000000018ef6d MPIDI_POSIX_mpi_bcast()  /localdisk/jenkins/workspace/workspace/ch4-build-linux-2019/impi-ch4-build-linux_build/CONF/impi-ch4-build-linux-release/label/impi-ch4-build-linux-intel64/_buildspace/release/../../src/mpid/ch4/shm/src/../src/../posix/intel/posix_coll.h:124
 5 0x000000000017335e MPIDI_SHM_mpi_bcast()  /localdisk/jenkins/workspace/workspace/ch4-build-linux-2019/impi-ch4-build-linux_build/CONF/impi-ch4-build-linux-release/label/impi-ch4-build-linux-intel64/_buildspace/release/../../src/mpid/ch4/shm/src/../src/shm_coll.h:39
 6 0x000000000017335e MPIDI_Bcast_intra_composition_alpha()  /localdisk/jenkins/workspace/workspace/ch4-build-linux-2019/impi-ch4-build-linux_build/CONF/impi-ch4-build-linux-release/label/impi-ch4-build-linux-intel64/_buildspace/release/../../src/mpid/ch4/src/intel/ch4_coll_impl.h:303
 7 0x000000000017335e MPID_Bcast_invoke()  /localdisk/jenkins/workspace/workspace/ch4-build-linux-2019/impi-ch4-build-linux_build/CONF/impi-ch4-build-linux-release/label/impi-ch4-build-linux-intel64/_buildspace/release/../../src/mpid/ch4/src/intel/ch4_coll_select_utils.c:1726
 8 0x000000000017335e MPIDI_coll_invoke()  /localdisk/jenkins/workspace/workspace/ch4-build-linux-2019/impi-ch4-build-linux_build/CONF/impi-ch4-build-linux-release/label/impi-ch4-build-linux-intel64/_buildspace/release/../../src/mpid/ch4/src/intel/ch4_coll_select_utils.c:3356
 9 0x0000000000153bee MPIDI_coll_select()  /localdisk/jenkins/workspace/workspace/ch4-build-linux-2019/impi-ch4-build-linux_build/CONF/impi-ch4-build-linux-release/label/impi-ch4-build-linux-intel64/_buildspace/release/../../src/mpid/ch4/src/intel/ch4_coll_globals_default.c:129
10 0x000000000021c02d MPID_Bcast()  /localdisk/jenkins/workspace/workspace/ch4-build-linux-2019/impi-ch4-build-linux_build/CONF/impi-ch4-build-linux-release/label/impi-ch4-build-linux-intel64/_buildspace/release/../../src/mpid/ch4/src/intel/ch4_coll.h:51
11 0x00000000001386e9 PMPI_Bcast()  /localdisk/jenkins/workspace/workspace/ch4-build-linux-2019/impi-ch4-build-linux_build/CONF/impi-ch4-build-linux-release/label/impi-ch4-build-linux-intel64/_buildspace/release/../../src/mpi/coll/bcast/bcast.c:416

When I try to reproduce the issue I find that there is a chance of about 20% to pass the test. It's 100% pass when running on  CentOS 7 and I have no idea about what happens.
To reproduce this issue, one can compile their own LAMMPS
module load intel/oneapi2021.1
module load gsl/2.8
# download lammps: https://download.lammps.org/tars/lammps.tar.gz
tar -xvf lammps.tar.gz
cd lammps
mkdir build
cd build

cmake  -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=gcc -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=g++ -DCMAKE_Fortran_COMPILER=gfortran -D BUILD_MPI=yes -D BUILD_OMP=yes -D LAMMPS_MACHINE=mpi -D BUILD_SHARED_LIBS=yes -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/public/software/lammps/29Aug2024 -D CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR=lib -D CMAKE_INSTALL_FULL_LIBDIR=/public/software/lammps/29Aug2024/lib -C ../cmake/presets/most.cmake -C ../cmake/presets/nolib.cmake -D GSL_INCLUDE_DIR=/public/software/gsl/2.8/include -D GSL_LIBRARY=/public/software/gsl/2.8/lib/libgsl.a -DGSL_CBLAS_LIBRARY=/public/software/gsl/2.8/lib/libgslcblas.a -D PKG_PLUMED=yes -D FFT=MKL -D PKG_ELECTRODE=yes -D PKG_KSPACE=yes -D USE_INTERNAL_LINALG=yes ../cmake

make -j 32
make install

And then use the follow sbatch script to run
#!/bin/bash -l
#SBATCH -p cpu
#SBATCH --qos normal

#SBATCH --nodes=1
#SBATCH --ntasks-per-node=64
#SBATCH -J std

module load intel/oneapi2021.1
module load gsl/2.8
module load lammps/2024.8.29

export I_MPI_DEBUG=6
mpirun lmp_mpi -i input.lammps && echo "mpi_success $SLURM_NODELIST" || echo "mpi_fail $SLURM_NODELIST"


Please include the [mcve] that demonstrates the problem you're having.  We can't help you debug code we cannot see.

Hi @TobySpeight I would like to but the main reason to write this issue is to share knowledge with others. I believe people with similar problem can find this answer by the error.

Putting away the "minimal" in MRE, your description is not even reproducible. Your build description does not produce an lmp_mpi executable. The only executable I can find is lmp_intel_cpu_intelmpi. Furthermore, you build lammps/2022.6.23, but in your batch script you load lammps/2024.8.29. I would not expect that these two versions are compatible. So, if you really execute the application that you built manually, combining it with libraries from the newer module will crash. Finally, what input.lammps do you use?

The tags and your description claims that the issue is related to the Intel OneAPI compiler. But you explicitly set gcc in your build script. Can you reproduce the issue with gcc? Then it doesn't seem to be a compiler specific problem.
Can you reproduce the issue with an up-to-date version of the intel compiler? The version you reference is one of the oldest versions of this compiler. Also, gcc/9.3 is old.

Hi @Joachim The reason to have tag intelone api is the intelmpi lib I use is from oneapi 2021.1. And you are right, I use gcc instead of icc to compile the software. Though gcc/9.3 is considered old but is still popular to compile scientific software. The build script is kind if as reference and I will update to the exact steps if you have interesting to reproduce this problem.

Thanks for the clarification. "software compiled with Intel OneAPI 2021.1" for me referred to the OneAPI compiler, which would be icx not icc. So the tag and the description is at least misleading. The main reason I mentioned that there are newer version of the compiler and MPI runtime is that often such issues are fixed in newer version of the compiler/MPI implementation. So, if the issue is indeed in the MPI implementation, a newer version could fix it.

Since there is shm/poxis in the backtrace log, I guess this issue may have something to do with inter process communication. So I try different options of I_MPI_FABRICS for multiple times on different nodes with sbatch --array and get the following results:



MPI Nodes#
I_MPI_FABRICS
Pass Rate
Note




1
shm:ofi
~20%
default option


1
shm
100%



1
ofi
100%



2
shm:ofi
100%
default option


2
shm
100%
It will fallback to shm:ofi automatically


2
ofi
100%




Though I still cannot figure out the root cause, according to the test result the best workaround is to set I_MPI_FABRICS=shm since it will have best performance on single node, and fallback to ofi on multi-nodes.
